# Accumulation of batteries' energy to rise electrical power capability

Tags: power, batteries, capacitor

I am looking for a method to drive/pulse (ocasionally) an inductive load from a battery. The problem is, that the battery does not deliver enough power the load needs. But, energy is not a problem. I thought about boosting the voltage and charging a capacitor, then almost instantaneously releasing that energy to the load. 
These are the batteries' specs:

- I_max = 200 mA
- U_bat = 3 V

Regarding the load:

- L = 500 mH
- I = 0,5 A
- P = 6 W
- t_drive = 30 ms

Of course, if something is missing, please point out and I will be glad to supply that information.

What I'd like to ask is if you see any pitfalls or would propose another approach?

@Neil_UK: The load is a selenoid. Which specs are missing you think?

@Transistor: 3 V is the battery voltage. The capacitor's voltage I want to boost up to maybe 16 V

@Joribama: hence I'd like to boost up the voltage since:
$$E=\frac{1}{2}C U^2$$

@pipe: I do not have the datasheet yet :/, just those numbers posted above.

@pjc50: Yes, boosting up the voltage is what I was thinkgin of, too.

Comment: charging an intermediate capacitor is an excellent method of energy storage to drive a load that needs high power pulses. Your load is not yet well enoiugh specified to tell what the pitfalls might be.

Comment: 3 V x 0.5 A = 1.5 A. Where is 6 W coming from?

Comment: Please also link the datasheet to your load, to avoid even further questions

Comment: Your numbers don't add up very well, as @Transistor pointed out. Assuming you need 6W for 30ms only, this represents 0.18J of energy. A capacitor to store that amount of energy @ 3V would have to be at least 40,000uF. Maybe a super-cap can do the job as long as its ESR is not too high.

Comment: This strategy - boost converter charging a capacitor - works very well for cash drawer solenoids @ 12/24V.